# Powershell IE automation responding slowly on new workstation

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, com

My group at work got a new workstation recently, and a script I've written to gather a report from a webpage is running very slow on it.   The new workstation is a Win7 Ent. x64 12GB RAM I5-3470 with IE11.  The older workstations are Win7 Ent. x86 4GB i5-2400 with IE11, so it shouldn't be a hardware issue or due to different IE versions.

```
...
$table = $doc.getElementById("T1020")
$span = $table.getElementsByTagName("span")

foreach($s in $span) { $s.innerText }
```

On the old workstations that foreach loop will spit out hundreds of lines in a second or two.  On the new workstation however it outputs maybe 2-4 lines every second.  It's not just that one webpage either, it does it on others as well.

Why would the calls to $s.innerText be taking so much longer on the new system?  Is there some IE or powershell setting that is limiting the speed?  How can I figure out what's causing this?

Comment: Are you running the 32bit or the 64bit version of PowerShell when doing your tests on the new machine?

Comment: That was exactly it!  Once I started using the 64bit version in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 it ran nice and fast just like the other workstations.

Comment: Someone pointed out that's the 32bit version in there, I'm not sure why it runs so much faster, but at least it's working now.